# regex to catch assembler C-command

Tags: regex, nand2tetris

I'm taking the Nand-2-Tetris course. We are asked to write and assembler. A C-command is in the type of `dest=comp;jump` where each part is optional.

I was trying to write a regex to make everything easier - I want to be able to compile the expression on a given line, and just by the group number, know which part of the expression I'm using. For example, for the expression: `A=M+1;JMP` I want to get `group(1) = A`, `group(2) = M` and `group(3) = JMP`.

My problem is that each part is optional, so I don't know exactly how to write this regex. So far I come up with:

```
(A?M?D?)\s=([^;\s]*)\s?(?=;[\s]*([a-zA-Z]{1,4})|$)
```

This works for most cases, but it doesn't work as I expect it. For example, lack of comp won't work (`D;JGT`). I have tried positive lookahead but it didn't work.

Comment: An assembler is a _parser_, and while regex may certainly be a tool you use, it is not the only concern.

Comment: Agreed. This looks like a case of "If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail". Regex is a powerful tool, but using it for this kind of task comes at the cost of your time and that of anyone who has to read your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx that you are looking for is as follows:

```py
(?P<dest>[AMD]{1,3}=)?(?P<comp>[01\-AMD!|+&><]{1,3})(?P<jump>;[JGTEQELNMP]{3})?
```

Let's break it down into parts:

- `(?P<dest>[AMD]{1,3}=)?` - will search for optional `destination` to store the computation result in it.
- `(?P<comp>[01\-AMD!|+&><]{1,3})` - will search for `computation` instruction.
- `(?P<jump>;[JGTEQELNMP]{3})?` - will search for optional `jump` directive.

Do note, that `dest` and `jump` parts of every `C-Instruction` are optional.
They only appear  with postfix `=` and prefix `;` respectively.

Hence, you will have to take care of these signs:

```py
if dest is not None:
    dest = dest.rstrip("=")

if jump is not None:
    jump = jump.lstrip(";")
```

Finally, you will get the desired `C-Instrucion` parsing:

For the line `A=A+M;JMP` you will get:

```py
dest = 'A'
comp = 'A+M'
jump = 'JMP'
```

For the line `D;JGT` you will get:

```py
dest = None
comp = 'D'
jump = 'JGT'
```

And for the line `M=D` you will get:

```py
dest = 'M'
comp = 'D'
jump = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to do, but based on your examples you can make a regular expression like this:

```
([\w]+)[=]?([\w])*[+-]*[\w]*;([\w]+)
```

Then for that line:

```
A=M+1;JMP
```

You'll get the following:

```
Full match  A=M+1;JMP
Group 1     A
Group 2     M
Group 3     JMP
```

And for that line:

```
D;JGT
```

You'll get:

```
Full match  D;JGT
Group 1     D
Group 3     JGT
```

See example here: https://regex101.com/r/v8t4Ma/1

Comment: This is still not good enought. I also need to be able to write `A=M+1` and it should work. and also, I also need to support operations such as !M (negate) -M etc. this is why in my regex I didn't specified which chars are premitted for comp, I just made sure I'm note catching something I don't want to (`[^;\s]`)